# Django Classes communication

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to build demo site with live sport streams.

We have 2 classes in Django
Class Team will be used to store in DB all teams in league
Match will be used to generate match stream page.
So once I did those classes Im trying to use shell and create the first match in DB
I created 2 teams with ids in db 1 and 2,but after I got stuck with creating first match. How to insert into Team1 and Team2  fields  Team name from (Team Class) with ids 1 and 2? by using shell at least for now.

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    league = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Match(models.Model):
    team1 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Team1')
    team2 = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Team2')
    link = models.URLField
    time = models.DateTimeField

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the `fieldname_id` to use the primary of the object you are referring to, so if you want to create a match with `Team`s with primary keys `1` and `2`, you can create a match with:

```
Match.objects.create(
    team1_id=1,
    team1_id=2,
    link='https://some.host.com/link/to/page'
)
```

Comment: Well. I checked the DB and yeah, its inserted but I need a team name in fields team1 and team2. For now I got 1 and 2 instead of team name in DB

Comment: I mean that Match class should contain in team1 = name of the team (from id 1 of Team Class). and same applies to team2 =. Team.name of id 2 )

Comment: @Win: that would be a bad idea. Imagine that you discover a typo in the name of a team. Then you should update all the fields, or even worse: two *different* `Team`s with the same name. If you have a `Match` object, you access it with `mymatch.team1.name`. You actually should think of a primary key as a "blackbox token" to identify an object where the fact that it *happens* to be an integer is an implementation detail.

Comment: Aight. Maybe you can suggest a better solution to this task? How to store teams and call it in match class?

Comment: @Wim: you fetch these with `mymatch.team1` and `mymatch.team2` where `mymatch` is the `Match` object.

Comment: I don't get it :(.  why I have to  use Match object using mymatch if I need vice versa :) ? As I understood, while creating a match using Match obj, In order to fill team1 name and team2 name  fields I need to call Team.name somehow, correct me if I wrong?

Comment: @Win: if you created a `Match` object `mymatch`, you can get the `Team` object that corresponds to the primary key with `mymatch.team1`, so if you want the name of that first team, you access it with `mymatch.team1.name`.

Comment: Aight. But could you show an example of shell request for it? using mymatch in order to create match?

Comment: @Win: you simply set `mymatch = Match.objects.create(...)` so you save the result returned from the `.create(...)` call.

Comment: im instrested in params in request honestly.   so It will be like = mymatch=Match.Ojb.Create(team1=Team.ojbects.id(1),team2=Team.ojbects.id(2) ..... ) is it correct?

Comment: @Win: no, you get the items with `Match.object.create(team1=Team.objects.get(id=1), team2=Team.objects.get(id=2))`. But if you have the ids, it makes no sense to first fetch the `Team`s, since eventually that is the same, and only results in more querying.